# How to use a MessageBox in a function

Tags: c#

I am trying to get function to take in two strings and show message box:

```
public void Myfunction (string str1, string str2)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("your message was " + str1 + Environment.NewLine + str2);
     }

private void Btn_Display_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string today;
        today = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        myfunction(TextBox_Msg.Text, today);
    }
```

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, $"your message was {TextBox_Msg.Text}", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")));`

Comment: This questions contains no text, but source code only. Is anything not working ? It all looks fine, except the curly paranthesis.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what's going on, say, what `myfunction` is supposed to do? Functions compute values.
I suggest showing message in *one go*:

```
    private void Btn_Display_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
      // Show message - MessageBox.Show 
      // of several lines - string.Join(Environment.NewLine
      //   1st line "your message was" + TextBox_Msg.Text
      //   2nd line DateTime.Now in "dd/MM/yyyy" format
      MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
        $"your message was {TextBox_Msg.Text}", 
          DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")));
    }
```

If you insist on *extracting method* then, let's first rename it - `ShowMessageLines`:

```
// Let's show arbitrary many lines (whe only 2?)
// Let's accept all types (not necessary strings)
public static void ShowMessageLines(params object[] lines) {
  // public method - input arguments validation
  if (null == lines)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(lines));

  // Combine all lines into textToShow
  // First line must have a prefix - "your message was " 
  string textToShow = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines
    .Select((text, index) => index == 0 
       ? $"your message was {text}"
       :   text?.ToString()));

  MessageBox.Show(textToShow);
}

...

private void Btn_Display_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  ShowMessageLines(
    TextBox_Msg.Text, 
    DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
}
```